# How to loft with rectangles to create a flexible 3D closed pipe in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rectangles, surface

I have a series of rectangles and know the exact locations of their respective 4 corners. I would like to plot them and loft through each of them to create something like a 3D pipe of rectangular cross-section. The points should also not be limited to follow a straight axis. It should be flexible in taking deviations. I would also like two the ends to be patched up closed.

I have seen a similar question about lofting on your website under "How to loft with ellipses to create a 3d hollow pipe in MATLAB or Python?". The answer impressed me but was sadly for ellipses and circles. I tried to make it work with rectangles but could not figure out the logic required. 
I also tried patching up everything together but that led to generation of sharp edges, which I don't want. My code looks something like this:

```
A = importdata(filename);

[size_A, ~] = size(A.data);
axis vis3d;

for i=1:12:size_A-12

    X1 = A.data(i+1); X2 = A.data(i+4); X3 = A.data (i+7); X4= A.data (i+10);
    Y1 = A.data(i+2); Y2 = A.data(i+5); Y3 = A.data(i+8); Y4 = A.data(i+11);
    Z1 = A.data(i+3); Z2 = A.data(i+6); Z3 = A.data(i+9); Z4 = A.data(i+12);

    X= [X1;X2;X3;X4]; 
    Y= [Y1;Y2;Y3;Y4]; 
    Z= [Z1;Z2;Z3;Z4]; 


    plot3(X, Y, Z)
    patch(X, Y, Z, 'g'); %% for the particular planes


    if(i>1) %% for the patching between two planes

        A1= [ X1 X1 X2 X4; a1 X4 a2 X3; a2 a4 a3 a3; X2 a1 X3 a4];
        B1= [ Y1 Y1 Y2 Y4; b1 Y4 b2 Y3; b2 b4 b3 b3; Y2 b1 Y3 b4];
        C1= [ Z1 Z1 Z2 Z4; c1 Z4 c2 Z3; c2 c4 c3 c3; Z2 c1 Z3 c4];

        plot3(A1, B1, C1)
        patch(A1, B1, C1, 'g');

    end

    a1=X1; a2=X2; a3=X3; a4=X4;
    b1=Y1; b2=Y2; b3=Y3; b4=Y4; 
    c1=Z1; c2=Z2; c3=Z3; c4=Z4;

    figure(1)
    grid on
    axis equal
    hold on
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('y');
    zlabel('z');

end
```

The end result should be like a very curvy pipe with rectangular cross-sections. There should not be any sharp corners.

PS: The MATLAB file is importing a notepad .txt document, where the coordinates will be inputted as shown below-

```
Number_of_sections= 7

X_coordinate= 60.00
Y_coordinate= 13.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 60.00
Y_coordinate= -13.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 60.00
Y_coordinate= -13.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 60.00
Y_coordinate= 13.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 95.00
Y_coordinate= 13.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 95.00
Y_coordinate= -13.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 95.00
Y_coordinate= -13.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 95.00
Y_coordinate= 13.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 95.50
Y_coordinate= 13.50
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 95.50
Y_coordinate= -13.50
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 95.50
Y_coordinate= -13.50
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 95.50
Y_coordinate= 13.50
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 96.00
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 96.00
Y_coordinate= -14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 96.00
Y_coordinate= -14.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 96.00
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 96.50
Y_coordinate= 14.50
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 96.50
Y_coordinate= -14.50
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 96.50
Y_coordinate= -14.50
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 96.50
Y_coordinate= 14.50
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 97.00
Y_coordinate= 15.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 97.00
Y_coordinate= -15.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 97.00
Y_coordinate= -15.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 97.00
Y_coordinate= 15.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 99.00
Y_coordinate= 15.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.00
Y_coordinate= -15.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.00
Y_coordinate= -15.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 99.00
Y_coordinate= 15.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 99.250
Y_coordinate= 14.7500
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.250
Y_coordinate= -15.2500
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.250
Y_coordinate= -15.2500
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 99.250
Y_coordinate= 14.7500
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 99.50
Y_coordinate= 14.50
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.50
Y_coordinate= -15.500
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 99.50
Y_coordinate= -15.500
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 99.50
Y_coordinate= 14.50
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 100.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 100.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 100.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 100.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50



X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 120.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -12.50
X_coordinate= 120.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -12.50

X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 110.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 120.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 120.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50

X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -7.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -7.50

X_coordinate= 70.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 70.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -5.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -5.50

X_coordinate= 70.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -2.50
X_coordinate= 70.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -2.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= -15.750
Z_coordinate= -2.50
X_coordinate= 80.0
Y_coordinate= 14.00
Z_coordinate= -2.50
```

[image: Here is the image]

Desired variation in direction Image 2
[image]

A little more detailed representation pof the desired variaion in direction Image 3
[image]

Comment: You need to calculate more points between your planes if you want smoother results. One way of doing this is to fit a smooth curve through all the vertices at the same corner and generate points on this fitted curve.

Comment: Is this your full code? I don't understand what you are doing with `i`. Have you also got some sample data so we can test your code? [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How many rectangles do you have? Can you post the rest of the code? The way I would do it is to interpolate each set of points corresponding to an edge to a polynomial, this way you'll have a smooth curve instead of the sharp edges.

Comment: @Anthony: The code is actually part of a bigger loop, where I input the data through a notepad file. Thus the use of the i as a loop.

Comment: @Renato: I will shortly post a better version of the code for a better understanding.

Comment: @Anthony: Your first suggestion is exactly what I am trying to do. Could you tell me a way to achieve it?

Comment: Hi. I have updated the code as EXACTLY how I have written it. It also includes the notepad file which I imported to get the coordinates of every plane. Please do not hesitate to make me change my approach. This is a full work-in-progress and I have no hard and fast rule that only my approach has to be followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was originally posted in my first answer, but the first answer gets too crowded and difficult to track. Therefore, I now separate this answer to a second answer. This is also an alternative and different approach to solve the question.

---

If you have a set of points with good density, you can use MATLAB's built-in interpolation function [`interp1`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

First, you need to parameterise the points. Chord Length is good enough here:

```
clear
filename = 'datafile.txt';
A = importdata(filename);

vertices = A.data(2:end);
vertices = reshape(vertices, 12, [])';

for i = 1:4
    % take a set of vertices that will form an edge of the lofted body.
    ishift = (i-1) * 3 + 1;
    p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);

    %calculate distance between two neighbouring points.
    dp = sqrt(sum(diff(p).^2,2)); 
    u = [0; cumsum(dp)/sum(dp)];

    % do more later
end
```

Then generate a new sets of u values for calculating the fitted points:

```
unew = unique([u; linspace(0,1,500)']);
```

And then interplate the points with `interp1`:

```
pnew = interp1(u, p, unew, 'spline');
figure; hold on;
plot3(pnew(:,1), pnew(:,2), pnew(:,3));
plot3(p(:,1), p(:,2), p(:,3),'o');
axis equal;
```

To summarise the `for` loop is now:

```
for i = 1:4
    ishift = (i-1) * 3 + 1;
    p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);

    dp = sqrt(sum(diff(p).^2,2));
    u = [0; cumsum(dp)/sum(dp)];
    unew = unique([u; linspace(0,1,500)']);
    pnew = interp1(u, p, unew, 'spline');
    x(:,i) = pnew(:,1);
    y(:,i) = pnew(:,2);
    z(:,i) = pnew(:,3);
end
```

However, since you only have 10 points for each edge, you will get results like this:

[image]

Taking one of the edge curves:

[image]

The huge curvature between V1 and V2 is clearly not desirable. However, since the variation between V1 and V2 only needs to be linear, you can artificially add points between them. For example, adding two points:

```
p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);
insertedP = (p(2,:) - p(1,:)).*(0.33; 0.66);
insertedP = insertedP + repmat(p(1,:),size(insertedP,1),1);
p = [p(1,:); insertedP; p(2:end,:)];
```

And then do the same calculation, you get:

[image]

If you add even more:

```
insertedP = (p(2,:) - p(1,:)).*(0.02:0.02:0.98)';
```

[image]

But it is not perfect since you will get visible oscillation at V2 which is unavoidable because of continuity:

[image]

However, it is controllable by removing or adding points close to V2:

```
insertedP = (p(2,:) - p(1,:)).*(0.02:0.02:0.68)';
```

[image]

Note that you also get such oscillation with the B-spline method posted in the other answer, but it is more controllable and predictable by moving the 2nd control point closer or further to V2.

A lofted body generated with the `interp1` method is like this:

[image]

To summarise, the full code to reproduce the above image is given below:

```
clear
filename = 'datafile.txt';
A = importdata(filename);

vertices = A.data(2:end);
vertices = reshape(vertices, 12, [])';

for i = 1:4
    ishift = (i-1) * 3 + 1;
    p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);
    insertedP = (p(2,:) - p(1,:)).*(0.02:0.02:0.98)';
    insertedP = insertedP + repmat(p(1,:),size(insertedP,1),1);
    p = [p(1,:); insertedP; p(2:end,:)];

    dp = sqrt(sum(diff(p).^2,2));
    u = [0; cumsum(dp)/sum(dp)];
    unew = unique([u; linspace(0,1,500)']);
    pnew = interp1(u, p, unew, 'spline');
    x(:,i) = pnew(:,1);
    y(:,i) = pnew(:,2);
    z(:,i) = pnew(:,3);
end
c = repmat(1:numel(x)/4,4,1)';
xx=[x;flipud(x(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
yy=[y;flipud(y(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
zz=[z;flipud(z(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
cc=[c;flipud(c)];
figure; patch(xx,yy,zz,cc);
```

If you have more points to constrain the interpolation, you can remove the lines involving `insertP`:

```
insertedP = (p(2,:) - p(1,:)).*(0.02:0.02:0.98)';
insertedP = insertedP + repmat(p(1,:),size(insertedP,1),1);
p = [p(1,:); insertedP; p(2:end,:)];
```

Comment: Yup it worked now and generated the required result! Thanks again a ton! Just one more doubt. When I am trying to insert a new plane at a distance of 10 from the last plane, it is not patching it straight, It's making it like follow a curvy way. I don't know how to post a pic of it. Maybe that could make it clearer?

Comment: @AbhishekBasak Update your question with the picture please.

Comment: Updated it as a link at the starting of the question.

Comment: @AbhishekBasak And where is the new plane? Can you provide the coordinates?

Comment: I have updated the question. The .txt file contains the new plane which I inserted. I also inserted some more planes (the part i the .txt  which has a little more line space) with different directions. When I am entering those new planes then I am getting an error at 'griddedInterpolant' saying the the grid vectors must contain unique points. The desired figures are show under images [2] and [3].

Comment: I actually understood the problem with curvy line. I have to insert the plane little closer to get my desired straight(-ish) line. But the part where I insert a plane as shown in my figure is still not clear. Did you find any solution for that problem by any chance?

Comment: Well I don't think you understand curve fitting. You can't just add points and hope the algorithm will generate a smooth curve. The points you have added no longer forms four edges and your desired lofted body is not formed by only smooth curvy edges too. You will need to break the curve where discontinuity is reduced to G0 or design B-spline curves with repeating knots to force G0 continuity. I suggest you to learn curve fitting and try working the math out by yourself. This is your work after all.

Comment: If you encounter problems during **coding** (not working out the math), start a new question to ask. SO is more fitted for solving problems directly related to coding. For math problems, check out https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AbhishekBasak You may also check this out: https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2019/04/29/makima-piecewise-cubic-interpolation/ Makima's formula looks like a better alternative.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help! Will do so as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Interpolating through the points in your data file cannot be easily done. I would recommend *design* B-spline curves to interpolate points between Plane 1 and 2, and Plane 6 and 7. Spaces between Plane 2 and Plane 6, Plane 7 and Plane 10 seem quite linear:

```
clear
filename = 'datafile.txt';
A = importdata(filename);

vertices = A.data(2:end);
vertices = reshape(vertices, 12, [])';

vx = vertices(:, 1:3:10);
vy = vertices(:,2:3:11);
vz = vertices(:,3:3:12);
figure; patch(vx',vy',vz',1); axis equal;
```

[image]

There is no easy way to do such interpolation because you want to ensure at least C1 continuity along the curve to avoid any sharp edge. B-spline curve could be useful here, but if you are not familiar with it, you will struggle to program it. Fortunately, I worked on a project requiring surface and curve fitting and I have the code at hand:

```
function [x,y,z] = bspline(u, ctrlp, k, knots)    
U = bspbasis(u, numel(ctrlp(:,1)), k, knots);

x=U*ctrlp(:,1);
y=U*ctrlp(:,2);
z=U*ctrlp(:,3);
end

function U = bspbasis(u, nctrlp, K, knots)
nu = numel(u);
umax = max(u);
index = 1:nctrlp;

% preallocating variables
U = zeros(nu,nctrlp);
N = zeros(nctrlp+1,K);

% Calculate the denominators for basis functions (k>2). -may be useful when
% the size of point data is substantial, so the calculation is not repeated.
d1 = zeros(nctrlp,K);
d2 = d1;
for m=2:K
    d1(:,m) = knots(index+m-1) - knots(index);
    d2(:,m) = knots(index+m) - knots(index+1);
end

knots = knots(:); 
knots1 = knots(1:nctrlp+1); 
knots2 = knots(2:nctrlp+2);
knotSize = size(knots1);
knotc1 = knots(nctrlp+1); 
knotc2 = knots(nctrlp+2);

for ui = 1:nu
    % k = 1
    u_ = u(ui)*ones(knotSize);
    NA = u_>=knots1 & u_<knots2;
    if u(ui) == umax && knotc1 == umax && knotc2 == umax
        NA(1:nctrlp+1) = 0;
        NA(end-1,1) = 1;
    end
    N(:,1) = NA;
    % k > 2
    for k = 2:K
        p1 = (u(ui) - knots(index)) ./ d1(:,k) .* N(index,k-1);
        p1(isnan(p1)) = 0;
        p2 = (knots(index+k) - u(ui)) ./ d2(:,k) .* N(index+1,k-1);
        p2(isnan(p2)) = 0;
        N(index,k) = p1 + p2;
    end
    U(ui,:)=N(1:end-1,k);
end
end
```

If you want to understand the above code, you may read through [B-spline Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). There are also lots of tutorials on Youtube and interactive tools such as [this one](http://nurbscalculator.in/).

---

The code below fits a 3rd order B-spline to each of the four sets of corner vertices.

```
u = linspace(0,1,500);
k = 3;

for i = 1:4
    ishift = (i-1) * 3 + 1;
    p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);
        
    ctrlp = [p(1,:); [0 0 0]; p(2:3,:); p(5:6,:); zeros(2,3); p(7,:); p(8,:)];
    ctrlp(2,:) = 5*ctrlp(3,:) - 4*ctrlp(4,:);
    ctrlp(7,:) = 2*ctrlp(6,:) - ctrlp(5,:); 
    ctrlp(8,:) = 4*ctrlp(9,:) - 3*ctrlp(10,:);
    knots = getknots(ctrlp, k);
    [x_,y_,z_] = bspline(u, ctrlp, k, knots);
    x(:,i) = [p(:,1); x_];
    y(:,i) = [p(:,2); y_];
    z(:,i) = [p(:,3); z_];
    
    [~,I] = sort(x(:,i));
    x(:,i) = x(I,i);
    y(:,i) = y(I,i);
    z(:,i) = z(I,i);
end
c = repmat(1:numel(x)/4,4,1)';
xx=[x;flipud(x(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
yy=[y;flipud(y(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
zz=[z;flipud(z(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
cc=[c;flipud(c)];
figure; patch(xx,yy,zz,cc);
```

The result is a smoothly lofted surface:

[image]

---

I wanted to explain to you how the code works, but after I struggled with it for an hour, I gave up... Instead, I provide a summary of some key points below.

In the summary, the following notations are used: C1, C2, ..., C10 are control points of a B-spline curve and V1, V2, ..., V10 are the vertices used to calculate the B-spline curve. The image below shows the control points and vertices used to calculate the firste B-spline curve.

[image]

1. The number of values in `u` determines the number of points on the final curve.
2. A 3rd order B-spline curve is sufficient.
3. The curve must pass through V1, V2, ..., V10.
4. To pass through V1 and V10, the B-spline curve must be a clamped type. Hence, `C1 = V1` and `C10 = V10`.
5. To pass through V2, C2 must be on the line passes through V2 and V3 and C3 must equal V2. Hence, `C2 - V2 = d*(V2-V3)` and `C3 = V2`.
6. To pass through V3, V4 and V5, the following condition must be met: `C3 = V2; C4 = V3; C5 = V5; C6 = V6`.
7. To pass through V6, C7 must be on the line passes through V5 and V6, together with  C6 being equal to V6. Hence, `C7-V6 = d*(V6-V5)`.
8. To pass through V7, C8 must be on the line passes through V7 and V8, and C9 must equal V7. Hence, `C8-V7 = d*(V7-V8); C9 = V7;`.
9. Since `C10 = V10` and `C9 = V7`, the curve passes through V8 and V9.
10. Finally, the knots can either be uniform or be estimated by the chord lengths between the control points.

---

## Update: `getknots`

The `getknots` function:

```
function knots = getknots(ctrlp, k)
d = sqrt(sum(diff(ctrlp).^2, 2));
ds = cumsum(d)./sum(d);
knots = [zeros(k,1); ds(k-1:end); ones(k,1)];
end
```

All in one code for the `bspline` method:

```
clear
filename = 'datafile.txt';
A = importdata(filename);

vertices = A.data(2:end);
vertices = reshape(vertices, 12, [])';

u = linspace(0,1,500);
k = 3;

for i = 1:4
    ishift = (i-1) * 3 + 1;
    p = vertices(:,ishift:ishift+2);

    ctrlp = [p(1,:); [0 0 0]; p(2:3,:); p(5:6,:); zeros(2,3); p(7,:); p(8,:)];
    ctrlp(2,:) = 5*ctrlp(3,:) - 4*ctrlp(4,:);
    ctrlp(7,:) = 2*ctrlp(6,:) - ctrlp(5,:); 
    ctrlp(8,:) = 4*ctrlp(9,:) - 3*ctrlp(10,:);
    knots = getknots(ctrlp, k);
    [x_,y_,z_] = bspline(u, ctrlp, k, knots);
    x(:,i) = [p(:,1); x_];
    y(:,i) = [p(:,2); y_];
    z(:,i) = [p(:,3); z_];

    [~,I] = sort(x(:,i));
    x(:,i) = x(I,i);
    y(:,i) = y(I,i);
    z(:,i) = z(I,i);
end
c = repmat(1:numel(x)/4,4,1)';
xx=[x;flipud(x(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
yy=[y;flipud(y(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
zz=[z;flipud(z(:,[2,3,4,1]))];
cc=[c;flipud(c)];
figure; patch(xx,yy,zz,cc);

function [x,y,z] = bspline(u, ctrlp, k, knots)    
U = bspbasis(u, numel(ctrlp(:,1)), k, knots);

x=U*ctrlp(:,1);
y=U*ctrlp(:,2);
z=U*ctrlp(:,3);
end

function U = bspbasis(u, nctrlp, K, knots)
nu = numel(u);
umax = max(u);
index = 1:nctrlp;

% preallocating variables
U = zeros(nu,nctrlp);
N = zeros(nctrlp+1,K);

% Calculate the denominators for basis functions (k>2). -may be useful when
% the size of point data is substantial, so the calculation is not repeated.
d1 = zeros(nctrlp,K);
d2 = d1;
for m=2:K
    d1(:,m) = knots(index+m-1) - knots(index);
    d2(:,m) = knots(index+m) - knots(index+1);
end

knots = knots(:); 
knots1 = knots(1:nctrlp+1); 
knots2 = knots(2:nctrlp+2);
knotSize = size(knots1);
knotc1 = knots(nctrlp+1); 
knotc2 = knots(nctrlp+2);

for ui = 1:nu
    % k = 1
    u_ = u(ui)*ones(knotSize);
    NA = u_>=knots1 & u_<knots2;
    if u(ui) == umax && knotc1 == umax && knotc2 == umax
        NA(1:nctrlp+1) = 0;
        NA(end-1,1) = 1;
    end
    N(:,1) = NA;
    % k > 2
    for k = 2:K
        p1 = (u(ui) - knots(index)) ./ d1(:,k) .* N(index,k-1);
        p1(isnan(p1)) = 0;
        p2 = (knots(index+k) - u(ui)) ./ d2(:,k) .* N(index+1,k-1);
        p2(isnan(p2)) = 0;
        N(index,k) = p1 + p2;
    end
    U(ui,:)=N(1:end-1,k);
end
end

function knots = getknots(ctrlp, k)
d = sqrt(sum(diff(ctrlp).^2, 2));
ds = cumsum(d)./sum(d);
knots = [zeros(k,1); ds(k-1:end); ones(k,1)];
end
```

Comment: Hi Anthony! First of all, Holy Moly! That is really a lot of logic and coding!!! I thank you very much for the effort, logic and time that you invested in this! The answer you have displayed is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I just have a question and a problem which I found while executing the code:

Comment: 1) I got the following error message when the program wanted to enter the  'bspbasis' function: " Not enough input arguments ". I am not sure where the problem is lying but it would be great if you could take a look again. I guess it may be because of the numel function?

Comment: 2) If I add more planes into the .txt file, would I be able to still generate th desired shape and form? And what if I add these planes in different directions (eg. maybe changing the Y and Z axis directions).

Comment: Also I wouldn't mind bying you a coffee! :) But I am a little confused if you mean actual coffee or the coffee like that on the link that you mentioned for the NURBS link? :D. Again thank you so much for your help. And the fact that you could do it in 30 minutes is very very impressive!

Comment: @AbhishekBasak don't worry about a the coffee, I was only joking. Curve fitting is not difficult for me because I have many years of experience with it. I have fixed the "not enough input arguments" error. I made a mistake in the code, sorry.

Comment: If you add more planes, it is likely you need to redesign the B-spline curve. The method I have provided is not universal, since the control points are  designed according to the current data points. If you need to avoid designing the control points, you will need to provide more points to reduce the gap between Plane 1 and Plane 2, and Plane 6 and Plane 7. Think about this, if you leave a big gap between two points, there will be less constraint for the PC to design a curve. The shape of the curve between a big gap can be anything as long as it passes smoothly through the end points.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Have to read it a little more thoroughly to understand the logic better. But I have another problem with the update to the old program. There is a function 'getknots' which MATLAB is not recognizing. Could you tell me how to define the function?

Comment: @AbhishekBasak It's a fun question to work on. You are welcome. I have added the `getknots` function at the bottom of the answer. Also added an "all in one" code so you can copy and paste it into your ".m"; it will run straight away, tested.

Comment: I have moved the second approach to a seperate answer.